# avoiding burns from the bottom of a single use soda-can metal coffee cup

Tags: thermal-radiation, thermal-conductivity

Would stamping a honeycomb pattern a few mms deep to the bottom of a small metal coffee cup prevent the user from being burned if the bottom weren't covered?

Comment: It would reduce the thermal conductance somewhat, but my feeling is that if you're putting a really hot liquid into the cup I would still be concerned about being burned. There's a reason that people generally don't make cups for holding hot coffee out of metal.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_filter_coffee actually in some parts of the world it's used a lot. Also, in Japan, hot coffee is served from cans in vending machines... Thank you for your point.

Comment: Don't drink coffee but I frequently travel to Japan and can't ever recall seeing any metal coffee cans with honeycomb patterns on the bottom. Also, was unable to find any images of the bottoms of Japanese hot coffee metal cans with a google image search. It's possible that honeycombing would work enough to prevent burns due to the bottom of the can, but even if so there would still be the potential problem of burning due to the hot sides of the metal can.